# Can I use conditional statement in place of key of python dictionary and if the conditional statement of that key is True then return value

Tags: dictionary-comprehension

[Conditional statements in place of dictionary key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jzsh.jpg)

How can I reduce this code using dictionary i.e. how can I use conditional statement in place of key in dictionary such that if the condition is True return value as desired in image attached

Comment: Hi and welcome, you should at best paste any code as formatted code text in the question. Attached pictures of code are not recommended. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary with the ranges as the keys. Use list comprehension to get the correct value:

```
wt = 2345

drng = {(-1,0):0,(0,2000):25,(2000,4000):35,(7000,9e25):'OVERLOADED'}

x = [d[1] for d in drng.items() if d[0][0] < wt <= d[0][1]]

print(f'Time Required is {x[0]} minutes')
```

Output

```
Time Required is 35 minutes
```

Note that for the last entry, you will need to do a separate check to get the sentence correct. For now the sentence will be:

```
Time Required is OVERLOADED minutes
```